# Pipe a Man Page to Kate Without Writing to Hard Drive

Tags: command-line, pipe, io-redirection, man, kate

What command will pipe a man page to Kate text-editor without writing anything to the hard drive?

I've seen examples that create a temp file (on the file system) and then open that tmp file with a graphical text editor.

However, is it possible to accomplish this task in RAM alone, without writing to the file system?

Comment: Keep your temp file on tmpfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kate` can read from standard input with option `-i` or `--stdin`

```
man foo | kate -i
```

---

source: `kwrite -h`

> `-i, --stdin` Read the contents of stdin.

Also, `-l` may be useful (for example, go to line one with `-l1`):

> `-l, --line <line>` Navigate to this line.